# Windows 10 laptop turning itself on and then freezing - why?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I've recently upgraded my laptop (Fujitsu Lifebook U574) to windows 10 and ever since, whenever I put my laptop to sleep, hibernate it or shut it down completely, it randomly turns on again and freezes completely (display off, status LEDs glowing) resulting in the need to do a hard-restart to make it usable again.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this? (I've checked the scheduler, nothing there)

Comment: Use Windows+R. Type "eventvwr.exe" without the ".  In the protocols you should see what happens before "crash"

Comment: Have you disabled fast boot ?